# Is it correct to compare unused key in object with undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I get an object from parent component via props, the value of key2 can be undefined. Is it correct to use comparison like this?

```
const { myObject } = this.props
const canAdd = myObject.key1.key2 !== undefined
```

Comment: The JavaScript interpreter would give you the best answer. Test your code on a browser. If you don't understand why the outcome is as it is, you can update your question to get explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `key1` is not specified your code will throw an error, because `key1` is not an object. You can assign defaults with object destructuring,

`const { myObject: { key1: { key2 } = {} } = {} } = this.props
 const canAdd = key2 !== undefined`

This code is saying, go pull the prop `myObject` out of `this.props` if its not there assign it to an empty object, then go get me key `key1` and if its not there assign it to be an empty object, inside `key1` go grab the value `key2`. If `key2` is not a property on `key1`, `key2` will result in undefined.